# Is PipelineModel thread-safe?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have a trained model exported to filesystem - `PipelineModel.save("PATH")` in a clustered environment. Idea is to use this trained model behind a web application and call transform method (`PipelineModel.transform`) for real-time prediction in a non-clustered environment.

Models can be loaded in two ways - `PipelineModel.load("PATH")`:

Approach 1- Loading the model for every request 
Approach 2- Loading the model only once (preferably during server startup) and use the same model for all the requests.

I would prefer approach 2   as it's faster. But the question is - is transform method thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

What do you imply by thread safety here. Its a static method that in turn invokes the following method which returns you a new Pipeline model instance. Re invocation of the method will return you a new instance.

```
override def load(path: String): PipelineModel = {
  val (uid: String, stages: Array[PipelineStage]) = SharedReadWrite.load(className, sc, path)
  val transformers = stages map {
    case stage: Transformer => stage
    case other => throw new RuntimeException(s"PipelineModel.read loaded a stage but found it" +
      s" was not a Transformer.  Bad stage ${other.uid} of type ${other.getClass}")
  }
  new PipelineModel(uid, transformers)
}
```

Comment: Well it isn't thread safe per se. But if your code does not change the pipeline model instance. I don't see how that could effect your transform operation. Do you have an example in mind?